# Tactile perception of printed advertising materials and brand image

Tags: cognitive-psychology, perception, sensory-perception

Does texture of paper (e.g.matt or glossy) of printed advertising materials affect the perception of brand image?

From what I've researched so far (http://entermotion.com/blog/2014/01/this-evolutionary-theory-explains-why-we-prefer-glossy-things/
https://www.psprint.com/resources/brochures-glossy-or-matte/), I found  research materials correlating paper weight and brand image but I did not find enough information on the topic of paper texture specifically.

Comment: An interesting question!  You might have more luck at the User Experience SE, though.

Comment: I guess higher quality and weight of paper would be associated with greater authority of the brand, by the mere association that a quality brand would pursue quality in advertising, as well. As far as the role of paper texture is concerned, I have the gut feeling that each type of pattern would suggest a specific perception, but I have no clue what.